# textAppearance not work in TextView

Tags: android

I show linked text in TextView.
At beginning , My code like this:

```
<TextView
     style="@style/informed_consent_check_TextView"
     android:id="@+id/accept_content_1"
     android:text="@string/informed_consent_accept"
     />


<style name="informed_consent_check_TextView" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#fff000</item>
</style>
```

It works alright.The link text display like this:

[image]

That's what I want.

However , after I move attributes about text into a style . It works wrong.

```
<style name="informed_consent_content_textAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">13dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#fff000</item>
</style>

<style name="informed_consent_check_TextView" >
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/informed_consent_content_textAppearance</item>
</style>
```

The link text display the wrong color:
[image]

And then , I move the textAppearance attribute into TextView. But it still wrong.

```
<TextView
     style="@style/informed_consent_check_TextView"
     android:id="@+id/accept_content_1"
     android:text="@string/informed_consent_accept"
     android:textAppearance="@style/@style/informed_consent_content_textAppearance"/>
```

My device is 4.1.2 .

Who can help me . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

make change in textview attribute

```
android:textAppearance = "@style/informed_consent_content_textAppearance"
```

Comment: Thank you. It's my mistake.And I modify the code before. However , the problem is still there.

Comment: change textColor to any other color like #ff0000 and you have write two time styles in your code.

Comment: two times? You mean textAppearance? I move it from @style/informed_consent_check_TextView to TextView's xml derectily last.It's still one time.